# c# timer is runing only once

Tags: c#, timer

I wrote small script that checks if app is running, if not it opens it. And I wanted check it every 10mins so I added timer but for some reason it only runs once. For testing purposes I reduced timer to 1sec and it loads app for first time, but do not open it again if I close it.

```
        private void Form1_Load()
    {
        //string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\isaced1\Desktop\FileMoverCheck\FileMoverV1.0.ini", Encoding.UTF8);
        string rootdir = @"C:\Users\isaced1\Desktop";
        Globals.files_loc = Directory.GetFiles(rootdir, "FileMoverV1.0.ini", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string item in Globals.files_loc)
        {
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(item);
            Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in ProcessList)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.Contains("iTAC"))
                {
                    Check = true;
                    button1.Text = "App is Running";
                }
            }
            if (Check != true)
            {
                Process.Start(fileContents);
            }
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1_Load();
    }
```

Comment: Where do you setup the timer and start it?

Comment: `Check` seems to be a global variable which is never reset, once it has been set to true ... so it will _stay_ true.

Comment: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement periodically called method *within* some *other method* (say, `Form1_Load` as in your code) have a look at [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0):

```
// Method should be turned into async
private async void Form1_Load() {
  using PeriodicTimer timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
  
  while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
  {
     //TODO: put here the code which should be periodically executed 
  }
}
```